# How to get dynamically link to thumbnail in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How instead of href="img/1.jpg, get the image thumbnail Url with WordPress function..

```
<a class="popup-link" href="img/1.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image thumbnail Url with WordPress function..

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); ?>
```

Sample Usage Example :

```
<?php
$imgarray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');
$imgURL = $imgarray[0];
?>
<a class="popup-link" href="<?php echo $imgURL;?>"></a>
```

**Reference to the codex**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_the_post_thumbnail` function.

```
<a class="popup-link" href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id = null, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' );"></a>
```

**Parameters**

**$post_id**
*(int) (Optional) Post ID. Default is the ID of the `$post` global.
Default value: null*

**$size**
*(string|array) (Optional) Registered image size to use, or flat array of height and width values.*
Default value: 'post-thumbnail'

**$attr**
*(string|array) (Optional) Query string or array of attributes.

Default value: ''*

For Details Visit
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the function `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>`
this `$size and $attr` are 2 Parameters and 
`$size is string/array` Image size. Either a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large, full), or any custom size keyword defined.
`$attr is array` of attribute/value pairs and it's `Default: None` let inside this how its works `$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim( strip_tags( $wp_postmeta->_wp_attachment_image_alt ) ),
    'title' => trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) )
);`
if you just use this without parameter `the_post_thumbnail();` then it gives default sizes post_thumbnail and
if you `the_post_thumbnail('large' );` then you can see the large size of images and you can changes both of this size via  `WordPress Administration Media panel under Settings > Media`
Now if you `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'anysize', array( 'class' => 'popup-link' ) ); ?>`
Or You can use `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); this functions for getting image URL and then $imgURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');
<a class="popup-link" href="<?php echo $imgURL[0];?>"></a>`